# How a DNS alias works if I create a new server with a named instance?

Tags: sql-server-2012

we had a server with a listener point to it:
Listener: database_db
server: Server123

The sql server here was without a named instance so you can just connect with Server123.

but now the server died and on the emergency we created a new server and I got to create a new instance over that one ( I can't drop it )

New Server:Server456\new_Instance

how that affects the alias?

if they change the database_db alias toi point to this new server/names instance, how that would work?

because I dont think just point the alias to the ip would work since now we have a named instance.

Answer (score 1):

> I dont think just point the alias to the ip would work since now we have a named instance.

It will work if and only if the named instance is listening on port 1433 on the IP that the alias resolves to.  If you have another instance listening on port 1433 on that server, then you can add an additional IP to the server and configure each instance to listen on port 1433 on only one IP.